# can't using post on google script

Tags: google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

hi iam trying to make post using google script , but it does not work,
original site here: https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg , it like you inquiry with code (ex:055) and number (ex:3020100) and it return bill

I try this before using python and it work but it don't work on google script

here is the code working using python:

```
import json
import requests
url = "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry"
data = {
    "AreaCode": "055",         # <-- change this
    "PhoneNumber": "3020100",  # <-- change this
    "PinCode": "",
    "InquiryBy": "telephone",
    "AccountNo": "",
}
with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies
    s.get("https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg", verify=False)
    resp = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False).json()
    print(json.dumps(resp, indent=4))
```

and this is the code i trying in google script but didn't work :

```
function landBill() {
  var url = "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry"
  var data = {"AreaCode": "055", "PhoneNumber": "3020105", "PinCode": "", "InquiryBy": "telephone",
            "AccountNo": "", };
  
  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  
};
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  var cont = res.getContentText()
  Logger.log(cont)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- On the python code you are doing 2 requests, a GET and a POST
- Since they are within a [Session object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) cookies returned by the website are being automatically managed.
- That concept however does not exist in built-in libraries of Apps Script, given that it has to be done manually.

#### Sample Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // =================== GET ===================
  //initiating a request object for the first GET request
  var request1 = {
    'url': 'https://billing.te.eg/ar-eg',
    'method' : 'get',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'validateHttpsCertificates': false, 
  };
  // Adding ('validateHttpsCertificates': false,) since it is the equivalent of (verify=false) in the python code

  var resGet = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([request1]); //storing the response to digest cookies

  // Digesting the cookies returned by the server (excluding cookies attributes) and adding them to an array to be reused in the POST
  var cookies = [];
  for (response of resGet) {
    var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (cookie of headers['Set-Cookie']){
      cookies.push(cookie.split(";")[0]);
    }
  }
  // =================== POST ===================

  // declaring the payload for the POST
  var postData = {
          "AreaCode": "055",
          "PhoneNumber": "3020100",
          "PinCode": "",
          "InquiryBy": "telephone",
          "AccountNo": "",
  };

  //Initiating a request object for the POST request and injecting the stored cookies into the HTTP headers
  var request2 = {
    'url': "https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry",
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'validateHttpsCertificates': false, 
    'headers' : {
      'Cookie': (cookies.join("; ") + ";"),
    },
    'payload' : postData,
  };

  //Storing the POST response
  var resPost = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([request2]);

  //Printing POST response content to console
  console.log(resPost[0].getContentText());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , it work , can you help me with converting other python codes to google script

Comment: In case my answer helped you, please remember to accept it. I'd suggest opening a new question if you have trouble converting scripts from python to Apps Scripts. Make sure to describe your issue and the community will help you